# Get HandlerMethod from WebFilter in WebFlux

Tags: spring-mvc, filter, attributes, interceptor, spring-webflux

When implementing interceptor with Servlet API I got `HandlerMethod` out of the box:

```
... extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
@Override
public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request,
                             final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handlerMethod) throws Exception {
```

Can I get access to `HandlerMethod` while implementing `WebFilter` instead of `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`?

In case of `WebFilter` I have:

```
... implements WebFilter {
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
```

Once I could access `HandlerMethod` by invoking `serverWebExchange.getAttribute("....bestMatchingHandler")`, but it doesn't work anymore. See [corresponding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838281/serverwebexchange-attributes-are-empty). My question here is: how can I get `HandlerMethod` without using `serverWebExchange.getAttribute`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer which helped to answer also my original question. `HandlerMethod` can be got this way:

```
(HandlerMethod) this.handlerMapping.getHandler(serverWebExchange).toProcessor().peek();
```

where `handlerMapping` is a bean of type `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` which you can inject from WebFlux.

Comment: toProcessor() is deprecated, so I used handlerMapping.getHandler(serverWebExchange).toFuture().getNow(null);

Comment: Saved my day! Chatgpt could not get this info even after the 5th try. Thanks man.